# Can I add switches to Google Chrome's AutoRun command?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I use a couple of (my own) Chrome Extensions that run in the background and I have the 'Continue running background apps when Chrome is closed' setting enabled in Chrome.

This causes Chrome to run on startup (when I login to Windows) which is exactly what I want.  Chrome achieves this using a registry entry.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-startup-window /prefetch:5

I want to add more Chrome switches to this in the registry.  However, the key for this registry value changes frequently so it's not possible for me to do that in the conventional way via script.

Similarly, I can't write a script that checks for the key name and writes to that because Chrome will start using a new key name at some point and break my changes.

Is there a way that I can tell Chrome to run at startup with my own choice of switches?  Enabling the 'Continue running background apps' setting in Chrome (which I need to have enabled) puts the startup registry entry there so I cannot just add my own registry entry.

What I need to add is:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --force-device-scale-factor=1 --enable-features=PasswordImport

So these switches disable UI scaling and enable the password import feature.  Currently, I'm running both from the desktop shortcut.  This works fine for disabling UI scaling.  The problem is that the password import switch has no effect if I run it while Chrome is already running in the background (which it will be as it runs on startup).  So I have to close Chrome manually and launch it again from my desktop shortcut with the password import switch included.

Password import used to be a flag in Chrome settings but Google removed it recently and now it's just a switch and this started the issue for me.

Many thanks.

Comment: The fact that the key changes shouldn't be a problem for your script: simply enumerate all the values in that registry section and hijack the one that has chrome in it.

Comment: Yes but I cannot do that.  If I write a script that modifies the current registry entry, Chrome will update at some point and start using a different key requiring me to run the script whenever that happens.  And that script would also create multiple registry values every time the key changes.
I need a solution where I can have Chrome auto-run with custom switches for the remainder of the login session even if it updates and the key changes.

Comment: Well, you can probably just substitute chrome.exe with your own runner that starts the original exe with the params you want. You'll have to redo it on update though.

Comment: That's the whole point.  I don't want to have something that I have to keep redoing again and again.

Comment: There's no other way AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just answer this question since I don't think there is a solution.

So I wanted to change the registry entry for Chrome so that it runs at startup with the password import feature enabled.  Unfortunately, this is not possible because Chrome changes the startup registry entry frequently.

My workaround is to keep the registry entry as it is and just have a custom start menu shortcut which runs Chrome with the password import feature enabled.

This is not ideal because it only works when Chrome is first launched.  Since Chrome runs at startup, this means to get the password import feature available, I have to manually close Chrome completely then launch it again from the start menu.

Still, the password import feature isn't something that's used frequently so it will do as a workaround.

The start menu shortcut I'm using is this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --force-device-scale-factor=1 --enable-features=PasswordImport
```

The force-device-scale-factor disables UI scaling in Chrome and enable-features allows the use of the password import feature from the passwords screen.